# Как написать анимацию с вращением?

Tags: javascript

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="blocks" id="blocks">
    <div class="block">
      <h2>1</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="block">
      <h2>2</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="block">
      <h2>3</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="block">
      <h2>4</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="block">
      <h2>5</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="button">
    <div class="btn" id="start">start</div>
    <p id="text"></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Есть вот такие блоки, при нажатии на кнопку должна запускаться анимация - блоки с задержкой по очереди вращаются. Помогите с JS, не знаю, как написать

Comment: Добро пожаловать на StackOverflow! Пожалуйста, добавьте к вопросу код ваших попыток решения проблемы, и более конкретные вопросы, которые возникли в процессе

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как-то так )

Стили добавил для наглядности

```js
var delay = 500

document.getElementById('start').onclick = function() {
  var divs = document.querySelectorAll('.block')

  divs.forEach(function(div, i) {

    setTimeout(function() {
      let deg = 0
      let interval = setInterval(function() {
        div.style.transform = 'rotate(' + deg + 'deg)';
        deg += 10
        if (deg > 360) {
          clearInterval(interval)
        }
      }, 10)

    }, (delay + 360) * i)
  })
}
```

```css
.block {
  background: red;
  width: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  height: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.btn {
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin-top: 20px;
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="blocks" id="blocks">
    <div class="block">
      <h2>1</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="block">
      <h2>2</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="block">
      <h2>3</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="block">
      <h2>4</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="block">
      <h2>5</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="button">
    <div class="btn" id="start">start</div>
    <p id="text"></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: а чему равна i в этом случае ммм?

Comment: Спасибо, еще порекомендуйте пожалуйста толковые книги по JS

Comment: https://learn.javascript.ru/